# I allocate a dynamic array of characters using pointer, and it gets run time exception?

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code, but when I allocate word in memory it gets NULL!
where is the problem with the following code? I forced to write in this why to split the lite into words :( please any help

```
void strSplit(const char *line, char *words[]){

    char *word = new char[81];
    int index = 0;
    int s = strlen(line);
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        if(line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != ',' && line[i] != ';')
        {
            if(word == NULL)
            {
                strcpy(word, (line[i] + "\0"));
            }
            else 
            {
                strcat(word, (line[i] + "\0"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(word != NULL){
                strcpy(words[index], word);
                puts(words[index]);
                index++;
                puts(word);
                word = NULL;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `line[i] + "\0"` doesn't do what you think it does. Why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: line[i] is a character and strcpy must used string so I must convert it to string through add NULL to the character

Comment: `+` on chars or `char*`s doesn't add characters. It does numeric addition or pointer math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (word == NULL) {
    strcpy(word, stuff);
}
```

This is suicide.

Comment: Also, why have two if statements which do the same thing?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins Exactly. And why add `line[i]` to a `char *`? Etc. So much wrong in this code I couldn't even enumerate all of them.

Comment: @AmjadOmari because dereferencing the nullpointer is undefined behavior.